# Display all the employees whose name contain 5 characters length in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in ORACLE DB where there are employee names column (ENAME) with **5 letters**. Query used was:

```
SELECT ENAME FROM EMP WHERE LENGTH(ENAME) = 5;
```

This is not returning names with 5 letters. Can someone please suggest me the correct one?

Comment: Does a white space `' '`counted? Define not working please. and also provide a sample data and the desired results as well as formatted text not images.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Examples or error message please.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what "not working" means.  Your question is unclear/too broad as currently constructed.

Comment: White Space are not counted. Under ENAME column, I have names like SMITH, ALLEN, JOHN, CLARK, JUNE etc. Now my question is how do I list all the employees whose name contain 5 characters length. Here Not working means when I give the above query it just shows the column name ENAME but does not list any names under that. My expectation is SMITH,ALLEN,CLARK should have listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [REGEXP_COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm) to count only letters

```
SELECT ENAME FROM EMP where regexp_count(ENAME, '[A-Z]') = 5  ;
```

> REGEXP_COUNT complements the functionality of the REGEXP_INSTR function by returning the number of times a pattern occurs in a source string. The function evaluates strings using characters as defined by the input character set. It returns an integer indicating the number of occurrences of pattern. If no match is found, then the function returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need 1st trim then use length

```
SELECT ENAME FROM EMP WHERE
LENGTH (Trim(ENAME))=5
```

Comment: What if there are spaces in the middle of `ENAME`?

Comment: have you ever seen first name & last name without space between them?? @user7294900

Comment: @Fahmi I don't know why you ask me, this isn't my answer, but yes, *Sher*

Comment: @user7294900 is there any info about middle space in the question? is that space will count or not?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin OP asks for 5 **letters**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking to count the chars excluding the white spaces

```
SELECT ENAME 
FROM YourTableName
WHERE LENGTH(REPLACE(ENAME, ' ', NULL)) = 5;
```

Comment: What if there are numbers? OP
 wants letters count

Comment: @user7294900 It's a guess since there is no sample data and enough information. My answer starts with _I guess_. And you can read the OP [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869318/display-all-the-employees-whose-name-contain-5-characters-length-in-oracle/57869488#comment102163754_57869318).

Answer (score 1):

```
select ENAME from EMP where Ename LIKE '____%'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also explain your code

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ENAME FROM EMP WHERE ENAME LIKE ('_____');`

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain to us how and why your code solves the OP's problem as code itself is not always easy to read.